# How can I group by date time column without taking time into consideration

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a bunch of product orders and I'm trying to group by the date and sum the quantity for that date. How can I group by the month/day/year without taking the time part into consideration?

`3/8/2010 7:42:00` should be grouped with `3/8/2010 4:15:00`

Comment: See also similar [group per hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour)

Answer (score 516, accepted):

[Cast/Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the values to a [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) type for your group by.

```
GROUP BY CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)
```

Comment: Nice one.  If this weren't 2008 with the DATE type, it would be a bit more messy but this works well.

Comment: do you know how I would do the same with LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @Nick - not sure. Try using `DateTime.Date`.

Comment: - Linq to Sql : `DateTime.Date`
- Entity Framework: `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(myDateTime)`

Comment: Combining DateTime.Year and DateTime.Month and DateTime.Day actually works in Entity Framework AND it works in LINQ to Objects too, which makes it a better choice in my opinion.

Comment: @NielsBrinch - this is pure SQL, without an ORM. Not sure your point is valid when an ORM is not involved.

Comment: I agree, I was responding to The Muffin Man who was asking about it in an ORM context.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it solved my problem.  added ' group by CAST(date_modified AS DATE)' . don't forget to add the same( CAST(date_modified AS DATE)  ) in select cluase.

Answer (score 32):

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, MyDateTimeColumn), 0)
```

Or in **SQL Server 2008** onwards you could simply cast to  `Date`  as @Oded suggested:

```
GROUP BY CAST(orderDate AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 17):

In pre Sql 2008 By taking out the date part:

```
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(8),DateTimeColumn,10)
```

Comment: For explanation about the convert function and date time type (meaning of char(8) and 10), see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 17):

CAST datetime field to date

```
select  CAST(datetime_field as DATE), count(*) as count from table group by CAST(datetime_field as DATE);
```

Comment: Repeats the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054176/861716). Please don't re-post answers. Instead, vote for answers that helped you.

Comment: @GertArnold it's not the same -- the accepted answer only recommends adding CAST to the GROUP BY clause, while this answer recommends adding it to the SELECT as well

Answer (score 6):

```sql
GROUP BY DATE(date_time_column)
```

Comment: There is no such `date` function in SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that I used when I needed to count the number of records for a particular date without the time portion:

```
select count(convert(CHAR(10), dtcreatedate, 103) ),convert(char(10), dtcreatedate, 103)
FROM dbo.tbltobecounted
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10),dtcreatedate,103)
ORDER BY CONVERT(CHAR(10),dtcreatedate,103)
```

Comment: The ORDER BY will not work as supposed because it will not treat it as date so it will sort by day

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example works fine in oracle

```
select to_char(columnname, 'DD/MON/yyyy'), count(*) from table_name group by to_char(createddate, 'DD/MON/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me it was pretty much straight, I used cast with groupby:

Example:

```
Select cast(created_at as date), count(1) from dbname.tablename GROUP BY cast(created_at as date)
```

**Note:** I am using this on MSSQL 2016.

Comment: Repeats the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054176/861716). Please don't re-post answers. Instead, vote for answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2022 you can use [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

If your datetime column is indexed this can make better use of the order provided by it than earlier alternatives.

```
DECLARE @Demo TABLE
(
myDateTime DATETIME INDEX ix_myDateTime
)

SELECT DATETRUNC(DAY, myDateTime) AS Date,
       COUNT(*)
FROM @Demo
GROUP BY DATETRUNC(DAY, myDateTime)


SELECT CAST(myDateTime AS DATE) AS Date,
       COUNT(*)
FROM @Demo
GROUP BY CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)
```

[image]