# SQL Server Group by Count of DateTime Per Hour?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, rounding

```
    create table #Events
(
    EventID int identity primary key,
    StartDate datetime not null,
    EndDate datetime not null
)
go
insert into #Events (StartDate, EndDate)
select '2007-01-01 12:44:12 AM', '2007-01-01 12:45:34 AM' union all
select '2007-01-01 12:45:12 AM', '2007-01-01 12:46:34 AM' union all
select '2007-01-01 12:46:12 AM', '2007-01-01 12:47:34 AM' union all
select '2007-01-02 5:01:08 AM', '2007-01-02 5:05:37 AM' union all
select '2007-01-02 5:50:08 AM', '2007-01-02 5:55:59 AM' union all
select '2007-01-03 4:34:12 AM', '2007-01-03 4:55:18 AM' union all
select '2007-01-07 3:12:23 AM', '2007-01-07 3:52:25 AM'
```

(with apologies to http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server for harvesting their base sql)

I am trying to find the count of Events that occurred in an hour, so the result set would look like this:

```
2007-01-01      12:00     3
2007-01-02       5:00     2
2007-01-03       4:00     1
2007-01-07       3:00     1
```

I have been playing with dateadd and round and grouping but not getting it. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

How about this? Assuming SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT CAST(StartDate as date) AS ForDate,
       DATEPART(hour,StartDate) AS OnHour,
       COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM #Events
GROUP BY CAST(StartDate as date),
       DATEPART(hour,StartDate)
```

For pre-2008:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,StartDate),0)   AS ForDate,
       DATEPART(hour,StartDate) AS OnHour,
       COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM #Events
GROUP BY CAST(StartDate as date),
       DATEPART(hour,StartDate)
```

This results in :

```
ForDate                 | OnHour | Totals
-----------------------------------------
2011-08-09 00:00:00.000     12       3
```

Comment: Sorry to ask question here, but lets say we have 4th column it has numbers, and you want to sum them by hours example at 12 hour, lets say we have 6 rows and each has 5 apple so it would be 30.

Comment: Add after Totals ", SUM(apple) as apples"

Answer (score 28):

Alternatively, just `GROUP BY` the hour and day:

```
SELECT  CAST(Startdate as DATE) as 'StartDate', 
        CAST(DATEPART(Hour, StartDate) as varchar) + ':00' as 'Hour', 
        COUNT(*) as 'Ct'
FROM #Events
GROUP BY CAST(Startdate as DATE), DATEPART(Hour, StartDate)
ORDER BY CAST(Startdate as DATE) ASC
```

output:

```
StartDate   Hour    Ct
2007-01-01  0:00    3
2007-01-02  5:00    2
2007-01-03  4:00    1
2007-01-07  3:00    1
```

Answer (score 10):

I found this somewhere else. I like this answer!

```
SELECT [Hourly], COUNT(*) as [Count]
  FROM 
 ( SELECT 
     dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, '20010101', [date_created]), '20010101') as [Hourly]
   FROM table) idat
 GROUP BY [Hourly]
```

Comment: Might need an Order by [Hourly] if creating a timeline

Comment: What would be the MySQL query for the above ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also achieve this by using following SQL with date and hour in same columns and proper date time format and ordered by date time

```
SELECT  dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, StartDate), 0) as 'ForDate', 
    COUNT(*) as 'Count' 
FROM #Events
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, LogTime), 0)
ORDER BY ForDate
```