# Grouping records between start and end time

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have a database of tests, each with a StartTime and (for those finished) EndTime value.
I want to create a query that would display the number of tests that were running each hour.

i.e. Tests that had a startTime but not an EndTime at any given hour.

I worked out the grouping thing  - with thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7001787/467473) from [@p.cambell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23199/p-campbell) to the question [SQL Server Group by Count of DateTime Per Hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CAST(StartDate as date) AS ForDate,
       DATEPART(hour, StartDate) AS OnHour,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalStarts,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(StartDate as date) <> CAST(EndDate as date) or
                     DATEPART(hour, StartDate) <> DATEPART(hour, EndDate)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) as StartedButNotEndedInHour
FROM #Events
GROUP BY CAST(StartDate as date),
       DATEPART(hour,StartDate)
```