# T-SQL Group by DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL query that i want to select count of sytem 21 in each hour of the date:

```
Select DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0) [Date],
Case when System= 21 then Count(CurUSSDCnt) else 0 end as Sys21
from table
group by DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0) ,System
order by [Date];
```

The Output will return somthing like this:

```
Date                    Sys21
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 3552
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 1880
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 0
```

Instead of:

```
Date                    Sys21
2015-06-29 00:00:00.000 3552
2015-06-29 01:00:00.000 1880
```

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour

Comment: Since your question seems to be missing key details which the current answers aren't meeting, perhaps you should review [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want information on system 21, you need a `WHERE` clause, not a `CASE` expression:

```
Select DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0) [Date],
 Count(CurUSSDCnt) as Sys21
from table
where System= 21
group by DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0)
order by [Date];
```

---

If you want more systems, then either use the manual pivotting shown in [ughai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31138250/15498) or use `PIVOT`:

```
select TimeHour,[21] as Sys21,[22] as Sys22
from
   (select System,
           DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,TimeStamp),0) as TimeHour,
           CurUSSDCnt
    from table
    ) t
       PIVOT (COUNT(CurUSSDCnt) for System in ([21],[22])) u
```

(If the `PIVOT` list isn't going to be exhaustive, you might want to add a `WHERE` clause to the subselect:

```
   (select System,
           DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,TimeStamp),0) as TimeHour,
           CurUSSDCnt
    from table
    where System in (21,22)) t
```

)

Comment: I am not only want system 21 they are more systems, but i selected as example

Comment: Thank u, but i wondering why my query does not group date time like example in my question –  Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1):

you should put `count` outside `CASE` like this. This will show all Hours even where `System= 21` record does not exists. also I changed `COUNT` to `SUM`.

```
Select DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0) [Date],
SUM(Case when System= 21 then CurUSSDCnt else 0 end) as Sys21
from table
group by DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0)
order by DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0);
```

If you want to only those hours where `System= 21`, use a `WHERE` clause as suggested by Damien_The_UnBeliever

Comment: There are more systems i selected system 21 as example, and i want to count each system by datetime, not to sum, here i have another query that i am comparing to output result,                                  SELECT DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0) [HOUR],COUNT(CurUSSDCnt) [COUNT]
FROM SmsProfile_Master30 Where FromSysId = 21
GROUP BY  DATEADD (HOUR,DATEDIFF (HOUR,0,TimeStamp),0),FromSysId  ORDER BY [HOUR]