# Ability to count per hour per day?

Tags: ssas

I'm new to SSAS so be gentle!

I have (simplified):

- fact table that has an ID, start date, start datetime, end date, end datetime
- A date dimension that has a granularity from Year to Calendar Date.

What I'd like to be able to do is get the count of ID per hour per date member/current member.  However I'm not exactly sure how to get there.

Fact Table Example

| ID | Start Date | End Date | Start DateTime | End DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-01 23:00 | 2022-01-04 05:33 |
| 53 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-01 04:00 | 2022-01-07 12:05 |

Wanted results:

| Date | Hour | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | 00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 01:00 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 02:00 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 03:00 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 04:00 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 | 05:00 | 2 |

I expect I need an hour dimension that somehow links to the date dimension and then some sort of measure that does a between comparison but not exactly sure how to go about this.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: above tables may not be showing right for some reason.  Looks great when I go to edit them...

Comment: check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001718/sql-server-group-by-count-of-datetime-per-hour)

Comment: Tal - this is for SSAS, not SQL.