# How to GROUP by DATE with same DATE but different time?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

How to `GROUP` by DATE with same DATE but different time ?

I using this code but getting error :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD') DAY, DE_NO
FROM (
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD') DAY, DE_NO
 FROM PACKINGAPPS_FQA
WHERE (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
)
GROUP BY DAY, DE_NO
```

The error is :

```
Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00904: "FQA_START_DATE": invalid identifier in...
```

Please help to advice. Thanks

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054144/how-can-i-group-by-date-time-column-without-taking-time-into-consideration

Comment: The error refers to the `FQA_START_DATE` column, are you sure that it's correct ? BTW, what is the data type of `FQA_START_DATE` ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade data type I using varchar. So any advice for that ?

Comment: As for the error - you've got an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19515544/1083652). As to how to remove the time part you can either use `TRUNC` (to make the time 00:00:00) after converting the string to a date or use `SUBSTR` on the original string. Anyway, I wouldn't store dates in varchar2s

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
GROUP BY CAST(datefield AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You inner query doesn't have `FQA_START_DATE` in the fields list so your first SELECT is incorrect.

Try this

```
SELECT DAY, DE_NO
FROM (
 SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   DAY, 
   DE_NO
 FROM PACKINGAPPS_FQA
WHERE (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
         BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
)
GROUP BY DAY, DE_NO
```

Comment: For DAY, it's not a column. I using DAY for AS.

Comment: Yes but your main query doesn't know `FQA_START_DATE` field it sees only DAY and DE_NO fields from your inner query.

Comment: OK, now how can I group by DATE ? With convert date from DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS to YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: @Kongkow Your `Day` field is already a date so just group by `Day`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
  WHERE DATE(coloumn_name)='SPECIFY DATE' 
  GROUP BY coloumn_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
SELECT field_name(s) FROM table_name GROUP BY DATE(date_field);
```

Here Date() function will case datetime to date.

[date-and-time-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date part of a date (without time), by using the `TRUNC` function. `TRUNC` will remove the time part.

The resulting value is still a date and you can use it to group by and format it as will.

I must admit that it's not exactly clear to me what type of value the field FQA_START_DATE is and what type the input variables are. It looks like they are all strings, but I would advise you to store dates as dates and also use date input parameters if possible.

So ideally, your query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
  FQA_START_DATE_WITHOUT_TIME, 
  DE_NO
FROM (
 SELECT 
   trunc(FQA_START_DATE) as FQA_START_DATE_WITHOUT_TIME, 
   DE_NO
 FROM P
   ACKINGAPPS_FQA
 WHERE 
   trunc(FQA_START_DATE) BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date
)
GROUP BY 
  FQA_START_DATE_WITHOUT_TIME, 
  DE_NO
```

And if you are not going to need any other fields, extra joins or aggregations, you can simplify it to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT /* Distinct will remove duplicate rows */
  trunc(FQA_START_DATE) as FQA_START_DATE_WITHOUT_TIME, 
  DE_NO
FROM P
  ACKINGAPPS_FQA
WHERE 
  trunc(FQA_START_DATE) BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date
```

Note that this assumes `FQA_START_DATE` to be a date/datetime field, assumes `start_date` and `end_date` to be dates/datetimes and will return a field `FQA_START_DATE_WITHOUT_TIME`, which is also a date field.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have any column with an alias `FQA_START_DATE` in your inline view (the `SELECT` statement in the `FROM` clause). You may have a column with that name in your base table, but that doesn't count here as you are `SELECT`ing from an inline view and not a base table.

Second, the `WHERE` condition in your inline view has gone completely berserk and it will return you all the wrong results as you are comparing a character value to be between two character values.

What I would instead suggest is you use the following query:

```
  SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) AS dt, de_no
    FROM packingapps_fqa
   WHERE TRUNC(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
         BETWEEN TRUNC (TO_DATE('$start_date')) AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('$end_date'))
GROUP BY TRUNC(TO_DATE(FQA_START_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')), de_no;
```