# SQL Top N by group query, N different

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table titled Company which has date-wise prices of all companies. I want to list the top n companies by price for each date, but the value of 'n' differs for different dates.

For example: I may need top 10 for 21st August 2014 but I may need top 20 for 22nd August 2014

I have the list of 'n' by dates in excel. Please suggest how to go about doing this

Comment: Please add table schema, sample data, your current query if you have one and your desired output, otherwise this is a bit too broad to answer. Try to give users that want to answer everything they need to write a useful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming `DateCol` is the `Date`-column, you can use a [cte](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) with `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK`(incl. ties)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT c.*, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY DateCol ORDER BY Price DESC )
    FROM dbo.Company c
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE  rn > 0 AND rn <= CASE DateCol 
                          WHEN '20140821' THEN 10
                          WHEN '20140822' THEN 20
                          ELSE 10   -- default
                        END
```

If it's actually a `DateTime` column and you have to truncate the time:

[How can I group by date time column without taking time into consideration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054144/how-can-i-group-by-date-time-column-without-taking-time-into-consideration)

Answer (score 0):

Lets Try the below Script,

```
If (select COUNT(*) from Company where date=21st August 2014)>0
begin
select top 10 * from Company  where date=21st August 2014
end

If (select  COUNT(*) from Company where date= 22nd August 2014)>0
begin

select top 20 * from Company where date= 22nd August 2014
end
```