# select specific one day data from day range

Tags: mysql

I have such script to query userCount from start of one day `'xxxx-xx-xx 00:00:00'`, to end of this day `'xxxx-xx-xx 23:59:59'`.

```
USE db;
SELECT user
FROM db.user AS user
WHERE
user.payTime BETWEEN '2017-07-12 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-12 23:59:59'
GROUP BY user.username
```

So now how can I query the user's payTime within the day from `2017-06-01` to `2017-07-12` ?

The first thing came out of my mind is declared a date range:

```
SET CURRDATE = '2017-06-01';
SET ENDDATE = '2017-07-12';
```

and put the script into a loop like:

```
WHILE CURRDATE < ENDDATE DO
   USE db;
   .......
   WHERE
   user.payTime BETWEEN 'CURRDATE 00:00:00' AND 'CURRDATE 23:59:59'
   .......
   SET CURRDATE = DATE_ADD(CURRDATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't `BETWEEN '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-12 23:59:59'` work?

Comment: @cwallenpoole because i want to query the data of each specific day，but not the range of two dates

Comment: Have you tried grouping by date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054144/how-can-i-group-by-date-time-column-without-taking-time-into-consideration

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT user, user.payTime
FROM db.user AS user
WHERE user.payTime BETWEEN '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-12 23:59:59'
GROUP BY CAST(user.payTime as DATE)
```